# How to trigger a .sh file or a bash command on a Qt4 button click?

Tags: qt, qml, qt4, qt-quick, qprocess

Right now, all I have is my QML file, with the button.

```
 /*PlasmaComponents.*/ToolButton {
    id: shutdownButton
    text: i18n("Shutdown")
    iconSource: "system-shutdown"
    enabled: power.canShutdown
    onClicked: doTheThing();
}
```

From reading about QML, it seems I'll need to add a C++ process. Is this possible with QML4? If not, could QProcess work? What files would need changing if so?

Answer (score 1):

you can write a process executor class like this :

```
#include <QProcess>
#include <QVariant>

class Process : public QProcess {
Q_OBJECT

public:
Process(QObject *parent = 0) : QProcess(parent) { }

Q_INVOKABLE void start(const QString &program, const QVariantList &arguments)                {
    QStringList args;

    // convert QVariantList from QML to QStringList for QProcess 

    for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length(); i++)
        args << arguments[i].toString();

    QProcess::start(program, args);
}

Q_INVOKABLE QByteArray readAll() {
    return QProcess::readAll();
}
};
```

and register them :

```
#include <QtQml>
#include "process.h"

qmlRegisterType<Process>("Process", 1, 0, "Process");
```

and finally run your command from QML :

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import Process 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
width: 800
height: 480
visible: true

Text {
    id: text
}

Process {
    id: process
    onReadyRead: text.text = readAll();
}

Timer {
    interval: 1000
    repeat: true
    triggeredOnStart: true
    running: true
    onTriggered: process.start("poweroff", [ "-f" ]);
 }
```

-f make forced to power off immediately.

Comment: I'm currently using QtQuick 1.0. Is using 2.4 necessary?

Comment: no, it isn't necessary, in the above code just needs a Process Item and the Process item defined is c++ side.

Comment: I don't know much c++, so this is maybe a stupid question, but what file should the register line be in? Can I just put it in the main.cpp?

Comment: #include <QtQml> is giving me a no file or directory found error, when trying to compile as an RPM. I've googled it, some people suggest swapping for  <QQmlApplicationEngine> and some speak to putting it in a Pro file. 

What's a pro file? and which include is best to use?